# Write a program that can pause/resume the existing running program

Tags: process, operating-system, signals

I need to write a program that will halt the existing running program in the system and prompt for a question. After answering the question the running program will continue. [This halt will occur after a fixed interval of time.]
I need to implement the pause/resume feature.

1. Is it feasible?
2. If yes then what would be the approach?

Note: Please ask for any clarification, If I am unable express my problem statement.